# Gridsome find current URL

Tags: vue.js, url, gridsome

I have a Gridsome project and I am looking to add `active` CSS class to the menu to highlight the current URL. For such action, I would need to know the current URL path in the Layout component to compare with the path.

How I can obtain the current URL or path?

Comment: Gridsome is using Vue Router so try `this.$route`

Answer (score 0):

Use Gridsome's `<g-link to="/"></g-link>` for the menu items, it will automatically add `active` class on the item if it matches current path. You can read more here https://gridsome.org/docs/linking/